# PHP equivalent to Javascript "with" scope statement

Tags: php, javascript, with-statement

Porting some code from Javascript i'm having this incovenience. For example:

In javascript we can produce this code.

```
var a, x, y;
var r = 10;
with (Math) {
  a = PI * r * r;
  x = r * cos(PI);
  y = r * sin(PI / 2);
}
```

Instead

```
a = Math.PI * r * r;
x = r * Math.cos(Math.PI);
y = r * Math.sin(Math.PI / 2);
```

In this last example will be the same comportament in PHP, IE, in second code example **Math** is redundant.

Someone have any solution for a clear an elegant code?

I'm adding the following code as new example:

```
class MyExampleClass {

    function example {

        for($i = 0; $i < count($this->Registers); $i++) {
            $r = "50";
            $r .= $this->ZeroFill($this->numericOnly($this->Registers[$i]->Id)), 15) . $this->ZeroFill($this->numericOnly($this->Registers[$i]->Inscription), 25);
            $r .= $this->ZeroFill($this->Registers[$i]->Model, 2 );
            $r .= $this->PadR($this->alpha($this->Registers[$i]->Date), 10 );
            $this->WriteRecord( $r);
        }
    }
```

In third example I can use a temp $var inside for statement for `$this->Registers[$i]`, but if all treatment code are became in a class like class Sanitize.

```
with (Sanitize) {
  $r .= ZeroFill(numericOnly($tmp), 15); // are much more clear and using OO
}
```

I want an way to do an shorter and no repetitive code.

Comment: Why do you use classes, when you want functions instead? See http://php.net/cos : No prefix ;)

Comment: Because in some situations, it reduces the amount of code typed making the final result more clearer and logic as the first example.

Comment: @AllysondePaula, in more cases, `with` introduces bugs. You should only use it if you fully understand the nature of those bugs and know what you are doing.

Comment: `With` really **can** introduces bugs, I agree. But in some cases a shorten code is more easy to read and understand the business logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is more akin to java than javascript, in java `this` qualification is optional and can be left out. The javascript's `with` statement is half functional as it doesn't even work with assignments.

PHP doesn't have that and you have to explicitly type out `$this->` every time.

Answer (score 0):

PHP scopes are very different than Javascript. I suppose the best I could think of is extend a class and using `$this->` rather than the class name everywhere - Do you have a use case you could share with us?

Comment: Kavi, I will edit the first post to another example. $this-> scope is redundant in this case

Answer (score 0):

[pi()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pi.php), [cos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cos.php), & [sin()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sin.php) are all reserved functions in PHP

```
<?php
$r = 10;
$a = pi() * $r * $r;
$x = $r * cos(pi());
$y = $r * sin(pi() / 2);
?>
```

Comment: I don't think the OP *literally* wants to shorten his PHP trig code (...or does he?). That said, an actual PHP use case from the OP would make things clearer.

Comment: Yes, I know... It's only an example - the third example (Edit in post) are more clear about my question.